# I want to use repeat(4) for this part of the code ${a}\_${b} only and to exclude the underscore from repetition to get the answer at the comment

Tags: javascript, repeat

```js
let a = 21;
let b = 20;

console.log("Write Your Code Here"); // _21_2021_2021_2021_20_
```

What would be the code?

Comment: What's in the title is the description of the problem. You should move into the body of the question and choose another shorter, descriptive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
let a = 21; let b = 20;

console.log(`_${`${a}_${b}`.repeat(4)}_`); // _21_2021_2021_2021_20_
```